# Magento 2.1 CMS Guide

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, luma-theme, page-content

I am building a new site using Magento 2.1 Community and am trying to add some fairly standard pages. I have no trouble adding these pages from Content->Elements->Pages->Add New Page but when I navigate to their link there is no header and footer on the page.

Looking for a guide link to how this is typically setup, I did run through the user guide and on this page:  it just has a note

"Now that your page is complete, it can be added to your store navigation, linked to other pages, or added as a link in the footer of your store. You can also use it as your new home page."

What are the typical steps I need to follow to add the site header bar to this page (or visa versa, not sure on the relationship there) and do so for all content pages I create.

I am using the default Luma theme. Various posts suggest editing a variety of xml files. Am I better served to create my own theme to preserve these changes or is there a module I should consider to make this process easier or is there a more complete guide that someone can point me to which will help answer this?

I am coming from a string familiarty with standard CMS's like Drupal and Wordpress as well as SaaS eCommerce like Shopify so aware of CMS fundamentals just not how they are handled in Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the layout of a CMS page - Empty, 1 column, 2 column-left, etc. You probably have "Empty" selected. Fix:

Content>Pages. This takes you to a table of your pages. Locate the row with your page. The "Layout" column specifies the configured layout. Click this to enter an editing mode. Select 1 column from the dropdown. Save, and reload the storefront page.

Comment: Thanks but I had already selected 1 column for the layout. I tried to duplicate the setup for one of the other standard pages exactly. That one is being rendered out with the header and footer content but my version is behaving as though it is a blank template

Comment: Ah, ok. Any chance there are javascript errors on the page? Right click>Inspect>Console. Additionally, you may have to clear the Magento cache...

Comment: That was the problem. Seems like this is actually a dupe of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125034/js-errors-magento-2