# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined during checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

During the checkout process on our production server, we are seeing the following JS error being thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined
at eval (eval at require.load 
(0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:175), <anonymous>:2:524)
at Object.execCb (0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:112)
at Object.context.execCb (eval at require.load 
(0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:175), <anonymous>:10:147)
at Module.check (0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:56)
at Module.<anonymous> (0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:72)
at 0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:11
at 0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:74
at each (0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:3)
at Module.emit (0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:74)
at Module.check (0a2bd8d76c9749ab612ccf3234146c23.min.js:61)
```

I know the stack trace isn't very helpful due to everything being compiled/minified in production and I'm currently unable to replicate in my dev environment due to some other issues I'm debugging, but I'm pretty sure the issue is the same issue described in this question here [JS errors Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125034/js-errors-magento-2), however the suggested solution hasn't seem to have any effect.

Edit: I have resolved the other issues in our dev environment, and can confirm it is indeed the same issue as reported in the question, but the suggested solution has had no impact.

This error appears to cause the 'Estimate shipping and tax' block that is displayed on the cart page to display as an empty block, see attached image below.

[image]

[image]

Anybody else ran into this issue?

Comment: @AshishRaj We've tried that command, as well as the setup:upgrade and di:compile commands, all of which have had no effect.