# Magento 2: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined

Tags: magento-2.1, autocomplete

I got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined.

So I checked the file in `/pub/static/frontend/Sm/himarket/nl_NL/Magento_Customer/js/view/authentication-popup.js` and did not find a thing.

Does someone have an idea? It says line 26: autocomplete: window.checkout.autocomplete,

I don't have a checkout window.

```
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'Magento_Customer/js/action/login',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/url',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'mage/validation'
],
function ($, ko, Component, loginAction, customerData, authenticationPopup, $t, url, alert) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        registerUrl: window.authenticationPopup.customerRegisterUrl,
        forgotPasswordUrl: window.authenticationPopup.customerForgotPasswordUrl,
        autocomplete: window.checkout.autocomplete,
        modalWindow: null,
        isLoading: ko.observable(false),

        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Customer/authentication-popup'
        },

        /**
         * Init
         */
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            url.setBaseUrl(window.authenticationPopup.baseUrl);
            loginAction.registerLoginCallback(function () {
                self.isLoading(false);
            });
        },

        /** Init popup login window */
        setModalElement: function (element) {
            if (authenticationPopup.modalWindow == null) {
                authenticationPopup.createPopUp(element);
            }
        },

        /** Is login form enabled for current customer */
        isActive: function () {
            var customer = customerData.get('customer');

            return customer() == false;
        },

        /** Show login popup window */
        showModal: function () {
            if (this.modalWindow) {
                $(this.modalWindow).modal('openModal');
            } else {
                alert({
                    content: $t('Guest checkout is disabled.')
                });
            }
        },

        /** Provide login action */
        login: function (loginForm) {
            var loginData = {},
                formDataArray = $(loginForm).serializeArray();
            formDataArray.forEach(function (entry) {
                loginData[entry.name] = entry.value;
            });

            if ($(loginForm).validation() &&
                $(loginForm).validation('isValid')
            ) {
                this.isLoading(true);
                loginAction(loginData, null, false);
            }
        }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below link for fix the issue.

[JS errors Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125034/js-errors-magento-2)

Also check for further details about that issue in github.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8532

Hope this help. Thanks!